# How to use relative path in selenium to save reports?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to save HtmlTestRunner report using relative path. The code runs without problem but no report is saved.
[Directory structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2zZ1.png)

```
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="../report/h.html"))
```

Comment: Could you please add more details and possibly an example to your question, as it will be easier to replicate and understand your issue.